# Max size of content in an iOS app

Tags: ios, ios4, size

In this post [Max size of an iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753100/max-size-of-an-ios-application),2GB is the answer for the max size of ios app.

My question is different. Here is

The app can download content from web and save in SQLite or any other persistent way. Or the app can use iTune file sync to transfer more content to the app. Whatever, my question is what is the max size of the content which will be transferred to the app.

The sure thing is that it will be depended on the available size. ( Please just ignore this factor here, thanks )