# Maximum sizes of iOS and Android apps

Tags: android, ios, upload, size, limit

What is the maximum size an iOS app can be? I have heard various answers from 1-2GB being floated around. Would an app of this size still have to be uploaded through the usual Xcode methods?

On Android, I believe there is a different setup. I have read that you apply for more space for your app and they come in 2GB 'chunks'? is that correct? And what is the story with applying for this space and uploading these mammoth apps to the Google Play store?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/4753253/1321873 and http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: iOS and Android are two entirely separate subjects. Please focus on one main question per post. i.e. "What is the maximum size an iOS app can be?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Max size of an iOS application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753100/max-size-of-an-ios-application)

Comment: I don't think that this question is off topic. I already know the max size of app on iOS and Android before reading this question. I still think that it is a good question and is ON topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android apps **had** a limitation to 50 MB. Google boosted this limitation up to 4 GB for about 5 months ago. The APK file has a limitation to 50 MB, however, you can attach two more 2 GB files, after download the APK file from Google Play. Fifa 12, and GTA III is good examples on this.

Comment: see here: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html#size