# Offline WebApp Game for iPad

Tags: html, caching, web-applications, cache-manifest

I'd like to make a super basic one-button space invaders game on iPad via an offline webapp (using the cache.manifest and canvas). Enemies would fly by your ship and you simply press a button to shoot at them, no left or right movement. Before I begin development though I'd like to know if it will even perform up to snuff.

Does anyone have experience with making simple offline webapp games? Would such a game perform well? Would it support detailed image graphics (not just geometric basics)? All I need is basic Flash level game support/performance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get good performance with [WebGL](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL). If you want an example try this HTML5 version of [Angry Birds](http://chrome.angrybirds.com/) that was developed just to show WebGL tecnology.

There are also many HTML5 game frameworks to help the development, some examples are:

[EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS)
[limeJs](http://www.limejs.com/)
[Impact](http://impactjs.com/)
[Gamequery](http://gamequeryjs.com/)

Comment: Are any of those optimized/meant for iPad? And I assume any of them can work offline as long as the app is below the cache limit (~10mb I believe). Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to worry about optimisation for iPad because we are talking about web technologies (HTML5 and Javascript). To run this kind of app iPad will use the it's default browser engine, that is Webkit. Webkit is also the engine used by Android, so the good thing is that your game will probably run without problems (if you are lucky :)) with Android.
About the 10MB cache limit, have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753100/max-size-of-an-ios-application

Comment: EaselJS looks good. Downloaded their demos and made one run offline using the cache.manifest. Seems to be working ok. The question you linked to is in regards to iTunes store distribution. For this I'm looking at web-only distribution. Thanks for all your help!