# Maximum Iphone Application size that apple store allows

Tags: iphone, ios

**What is the maximum application size that apple store allows for an iphone application or game.**

Answer (score 2):

2GB's is the maximum size your iOS app can be. Check [Max size of an iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753100/max-size-of-an-ios-application)

Comment: You have enough reputation to cast close votes and you knew that it was a duplicate, why did you choose to make this an answer instead of a close vote?

Comment: If you see exact same question, you may answer it with a **Vote for Close**. Otherwise 100s of dupes will be floating in SO, and that will annoy you and others isn't it?

Comment: I have not enough reputation to close this question but i flag this question as duplicate already...I share original answer here...

Comment: @Vishal Whoops, you are right, sorry, I thought it was 2,5k rep! However, I think this should've been a comment instead of an answer (but that's up to you, I thought that you could cast close votes so that's why I added the comment in the first place).

Comment: NO bro don't say sorry to me its ok...I will take care of this thing next time.

Answer (score 0):

Up to 2 Gb your iOS app can be.

Comment: How is this different from an already posted answer and a comment below the question? If you are going to put same answer, please **Don't** instead give a +1 to other, with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

2 GBs is the maximum size your iOS app can be.

> As of January 10, 2013
>
> (iOS only) App Size Tips
>
> iOS apps can be as large as 2 GB, but consider download times when
>   determining your app's size.
>
> Minimize the file’s size as much as possible, keeping in mind that
>   there is a 50 MB limit for over-the-air downloads.