# How many records can be reindexed in sql-lite on IPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I have to implement an application in IOS which will be storing data on IPhone local storage. For example on device there can be yearly 3 million records by a user, so does IPhone will be able to process these many number of records?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If there is a limit, it will not be number of rows, but storage space you take. If one row of your database is say 100 bytes, db size will be about 300MB. Since max size for the app [is currently 2GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753100/max-size-of-an-ios-application), it should work, unless your database row is wider than about 500+ bytes.

Comment: But the maximum size of app which you are referring is for App Store app which will be uploaded. My point is like after installing my app user can save data in my app, I was concerned about database size as user will go on using/saving data on my app?