# Max size of data an iOS can save locally

Tags: ios

Is there a limit to the maximum size of data my iOS app can store on the device.
This is not the size of the App but the data it can store.

Answer (score 3):

You are only limited by the storage capacity of the device. The 2GB maximum (per https://stackoverflow.com/a/4753253/1415038) only applies to your app before it is downloaded from the app store.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think Apple has set a limit for storing app data so far. No mention is made of a data storage limit in their "The iOS Environment" [document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html) or the "About Files and Directories" [document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672).