# Xamarin 4.0.10 with Xcode 5.0 won't run on device but do run in simulator

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xcode5

I have that problem where I updated Xamarin and Xcode to their latest stable version.

My app will run on the Simulator, but won't run on the Device. It will install, then it will crash just after the Launch Screen, and it doesn't give any Error in the IDE.

I tried on another computer where Xamarin is on the same version, but Xcode is still on the 4.X ... and it launch with success and run as it should on the device.

So, is it just a problem with Xamarin and Xcode 5 compatibility ? Can I do something to fix that problem, any tips to solve this problem will be grateful.

Comment: Have you looked at the crash logs from your device? They should give you clues on the error.

Comment: Yes I did, unfortunately it is not really helpful for this case, otherwise I found a solution, I have installed Xcode 4.6 and changed the link in Xamarin for that SDK, since it is not ready for iOS 7.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Can't return to 4.6. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Actually I have re-installed XCode 4.6 and I am still using it for developpment. Eventually, i'll have to do the merge on Xcode 5. In Fact, I had a couple of problems running simulator/device with Xamarin mainly due to the C# things, careful with the Dynamic Class <T>.

Answer (score 1):

What might be happening (that is happening to me) is that the resulting exe is too big.

I have an app that uses servicestack. Before xcode 4.6 it worked, after xcode 5 it does not work.

With Xamarin support and some research I realized that the "estimated size" for the "archive" in organizer was bigger than 62mb. Whenever that happens my app is killed before starting.

I am in the process of slimming down servicestack, but preliminarily it is working.

**Bottom line: check the size of your exe. See limitation: [Max size of an iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753100/max-size-of-an-ios-application)**