# executable file vs binary file..how they work?

Tags: ios, ios7, app-store

Apple states that an iOS App binary file can be as large as 2 GB, but the executable file (app_name.app/app_name) cannot exceed 60 MB? Does that mean that on the App Store, when I download my app that it can be as large as 2 GB? Or is it required that my app be less than 60 MB including all my images and video?

If my app including images and video must be less than 60 MB, how can I retrieve the rest of my assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .app file portion is limited to 60 MB and consist largely of your compiled code. When combined with the assets (images, sounds, videos, data, etc.) in an .ipa file, the maximum size is 2 GB.

Note that these limits change over time. See: [Max size of an iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753100/max-size-of-an-ios-application)

Comment: okk..when user download my app what size of file he download ?? if my app contain appro. 2gb data then, my app size become 2gb and user download 2gb of data..am i right??