# App Store File Size Warning in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, objective-c, size, app-store-connect

Version 1.0 of my app has finally been completed. It's a simple application with the ability to view multiple leaflets and links to videos from a charity-based organisation. I've uploaded it to iTunes Connect for the final build, but I'm seeing a "App Store File Size Warning" in iTunes Connect.

[image]

The app itself contains 220 images (each has an average size of 500 Kb but some much smaller). The idea of the app is to have the charity's leaflets all accessible within the app in an offline state (hence why they're not downloaded from a server somewhere, etc).

The app itself also contains links to the companies videos. So the videos itself are not in the app, but rather links to the videos are populating the app's `UITableViewCells`.

Reading many questions about App Store size reduction, I have moved 1200 titles and URLs for the videos to text files rather than storing them in code. I have reduced the sizes of the images (they can't be reduced anymore because they will become low resolution). I'm just not too sure what I can do to get to the required limit? Or, could I still submit as it's only a warning and not an error?

For example, I downloaded a game today that was 190Mb. How does that get around this?

The app supports iOS 7, 8 and 9, so I can't use App Thinning just for that. I see some information on this: [Max size of an iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753100/max-size-of-an-ios-application) but it's not new, etc.

Is it possible for me to bypass the warning in iTunes Connect and submit anyway? (I'll submit after the ITC X mas break).

Any thoughts on this would be really appreciated. 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That won't cause any issue. If your app is less than 100 MB the warning won't be there. Apple prefers to keep the IPA size below 100 MB for keeping the app mobile data friendly (To download using mobile data).

There are several ways you can reduce the size:

1. Use App Thinning
2. Implement an one time download mechanism in your app, through which download the files on first start (I'm doing such a mechanism in 3 of my app, that needs around 300 MB of resource for proper working)

You can read more techniques in [Reducing the size of my App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1795/_index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response @Midhun - that's what I thought as well - I believed it was to do with mobile-data, etc. So with that in mind, when it comes to submitting, even though my app is 209 Mb, I can still submit without issues? (of course there might be other things, but I mean specifically related to the size, etc). Just wanted to confirm with you.

Comment: @amitsbajaj: I have two apps 1 above 200 MB and 1 around 120 MB size in AppStore. I got same warning from AppStore but didn't had any issue in app reviewing

Comment: Thanks so much @Midhun - that's really, really helpful and I appreciate your prompt answer. I also appreciate the resources you have mentioned with App Thinning and Implementing a one time download - definitely something to look into, going forward. Thanks again and happy holidays!