# Qt5/QML application for iOS file huge bundle size issue

Tags: ios, xcode, qt, clang, qt-quick

I'm studying QML technology now.
To take a look of Qt Quick Controls, i've opened the *Qt Quick Controls Gallery* example from the Qt Creator. Then i examine the qmake's output directory...

In **release** build mode i've got **~40** Mb application bundle!
And the main "weight" into it has the executable file. Not the resources, as it usually occurs.
It is dangerously close to Apple AppStore **60 Mb** for each executable limit :( (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753100/max-size-of-an-ios-application))
My own application will use many 3rd-party libraries, so it can easily exceeds it.

Any ideas how i can "shrink" the executable size?

Qt Modules used:

```
QT += qml
QT += quick
QT += widgets
QT += network
QT += xml
QT += svg
```

iOS-specific `qmake` stuff:

```
ios {
    TARGET = MyApp
    QMAKE_IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 6.0
    CONFIG += console
    QMAKE_INFO_PLIST = ios/MyApp.plist

    ...

    OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += ../ios/nativestuff.mm
    LIBS += -framework UIKit
}
```

*P.S.*: i already ensured what debug information was disabled, and "strip all symbols" - enabled in XCode. However, looks like Qt libraries itself have huge size. I've already recompiled Qt for Windows to get rid of fat ICU, but under iOS i don't know the reason why it is so big.

*P.P.S.* I used Qt 5.5.1, i was unable to download new 5.6 one. Maybe in this version libs are smaller?

Comment: Have you got Qt built statically? Can you give us an overview of what's included?

Comment: Yes, as far as i know, Qt for iOS uses static linking. What you mean by "included" - what Qt modules i used, or some OS X version of `dumpbin` output?

Comment: Yeah which Qt modules are you using.

Comment: Done, the answer was updated

Comment: If you're using QML + Quick you probably don't need to use `qt += widgets`, unless you're mixing widgets and QML. The `widgets` import will be pretty heavy in terms of binary use.

Comment: Unfortunately, i have to used some legacy code what used Qt Widgets. But this is not a reason: Qt Quick Controls Gallery example don't use widgets, but it is very big too!