# What is the actual filesize limit for iTunes connect app?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an image-heavy application I'm trying to submit for beta review on test-flight. Currently it targets Universal.  When I upload it, it says "in beta review" but it also shows me this warning:

> App Store file sizes for Build 0.0.3 exceed the 100 MB app file limit.
>   View App Store file sizes.

So, is it in review or not? **Should I not build a universal binary?** Also, the link to the "app store file sizes" is broken (js error). Now, I've seen some [press releases](http://9to5mac.com/2015/02/12/apple-increases-app-size-limit-4gb/) saying they are now allowing 4 GB apps. I thought the 100 MB limit is only for over-the-air installs, not binary size for apps.

> The universal device type variant will be downloaded only by customers
>   using iOS earlier than iOS 9.0. If any of the device variant sizes
>   exceed the 100 MB over-the-air download limit, a yellow warning will
>   display next to the variant size in the table. Apple will also send
>   you an email with this information.

How can I get around this? I do not need to support iOS 8. If that's what's causing this, how can I disable iOS 8 in my xCode build? This is a cordova-based app, so I'm not sure I can do resource tags.

I am going to try *not* doing a universal binary under the "deployment info" tab... Do I just need to specify the "deployment target" to 9? Do I need to further limit the specific devices?

Comment: Literally 5 minutes after I posted this question, I got an email: "Your app has been approved for distribution through Apple’s TestFlight Program." so, does this mean that I just need to not target iOS 8 then for eventual App Store submission?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Max size of an iOS application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753100/max-size-of-an-ios-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it you are limited to 100 MB for cellular installation and 4 GB for WiFi installation.

You probably get a warning when your app is bigger than 100 MB because you're over the cellular limit.