# What is maximum size of ipa (iphone or ipad) app allow in itune to upload?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an application having video embadded into it. The size of video is too large due to that ipa size exceed 1Gb almost. So please somebody tell me what is the maximum size limit of an application of (iphone or ipad) on for distribution.I have search in apple documentation but cannot able to understand.I have also refer this link below which is same as apple doc
I don't have enough points to comment on any others post to ask them. So please help
[Max size of an iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753100/max-size-of-an-ios-application)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't understand the answers for a question, leave a comment under the answer, don't ask a new question with the exact same content.

Comment: Not able to comment on that I don't have reputation 50 to comment. PLease I if you know tell me.  I need just a small help