# Augmented Reality based application maximum size for app store release?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, arkit

I am developing an application based on Augmented Reality. I want to know what is the maximum size of the application can be upload for the app store.

I planned to add all my 3D models locally into my project. Will I face any barriers upon release?

What is uncompressed file size?
I couldn't understand the terms names that apple used. Can you explain clearly?

I have read this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753100/max-size-of-an-ios-application)

They mentioned max size 4GB for uncompressed and 500 MB for app_name.app/app_name. What is this means, where can I find this files location?

GTA (Grand Theft Auto) game app's size is 1.5 GB. Is it possible for me to import all 3D models into my app(72 3D models)