# An iOS app internal size?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, memory, document-directory

I have searched for an iOS app internal size but find no exact answer.

I know an iOS app size in app-store could be 2GB. But my question is, is there any limitation on iOS internal app size.

For example, I could download video or images to iPhone through my app. And store it to Db or project's document directory.

So is it possible to use whole iPhone Memory or there is any limitation regarding each application?

Comment: I don't think there's a limit, just make sure you're not storing big files in the documents folder because your app might be rejected. Here's some info about storage. https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html

Comment: here is answer 4GB's is the maximum size
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4753253/8687925

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit to how much additional content you can download (other than the storage space, of course). But there are guidelines for where and how to store the data, such as applying the "do not back up" attribute for files that must remain on the device and/or large recreate-able files and store non-recreate-able content in documents.